# XML Parsing from URL is not working in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to implement `XML Parsing` from `url`. Below is the code for using `xml` parsing but it is not working. Can anybody help me to get `response` accordingly.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declare variables
    TextView textview;
    NodeList nodelist;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Insert image URL
//    String URL = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/XMLParseTutorial.xml";
    String URL = "my private url";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadXML().execute(URL);

        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    }


    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressbar
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressbar title
            pDialog.setTitle("Android Simple XML Parsing using DOM Tutorial");
            // Set progressbar message
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressbar
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                // Download the XML file
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                Log.e("testing "," ==>");


                // Locate the Tag Name
//                nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("ApiResponseOfTwiliosZ_PlQ1mzg");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nodelist.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nodelist.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    // Set the texts into TextViews from item nodes
                    // Get the title


                    Log.e("Message checking "," ===> "+getNode("ResponseStatus", eElement));



                }
            }
            // Close progressbar
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // getNode function
    private static String getNode(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
                .getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
        return nValue.getNodeValue();
    }
}
```

and error look like below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int org.w3c.dom.NodeList.getLength()' on a null object reference
```

[image]

Here I want to get `token` from this response.

Below is my `api response`

```
    <ApiResponseOfTwiliosZ_PlQ1mzg xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Healthcare4Free.WebApi.Models">
<Data i:nil="true"/>
<ResponseStatus>
<Message>Success</Message>
<StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
<TwilioToken>
<Token>
eyJjdHkiOiJ0d2lsaW8tZnBhO3Y9MSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2In0.eyJpc3MiOiJTSzMxZDVjM2NiNDVmMjQ2ZjI5NDY4MTFlOGQxYWZlYjM4IiwiZXhwIjoxNTA4Njc4NzYzLCJqdGkiOiJTSzMxZDVjM2NiNDVmMjQ2ZjI5NDY4MTFlOGQxYWZlYjM4LTE1MDg2NzUxNjMiLCJzdWIiOiJBQzdlNDBhZjY1YTYwMGYyYmQ3Yjg2Zjk1OTFkZjM4ZTFiIiwiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoiaWRlbnRpdHkiLCJ2aWRlbyI6eyJyb29tIjoicm9vbUlkIn19fQ.yHKcOOiUrVZKYsQ3110YzgprRpODd9fp1dQLQFNw7Gw
</Token>
</TwilioToken>
</ResponseStatus>
</ApiResponseOfTwiliosZ_PlQ1mzg>
```

Comment: Your nodelist is null.Error may be in     nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("ApiResponseOfTwiliosZ_PlQ1mzg");

Comment: @ M M Thanks for reply but can you help me with sample code so that it is easy for me to integrate it.

Comment: @M M Thank you for your quick response. Actually i can't share original url but it is fully working which response attached into this image in this question. I need sample code to get appropriate response. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add XML instead of image

Comment: I have update `api` response into question which show into images. Kindly check it from your side and let me know accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Token Update your Code as:

In doInBackground()

```
nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("TwilioToken");
```

In your onPostExecute()

```
Log.e("Message checking ", " ===> " + getNode("Token", eElement));
```

Here is the full Code:

```
TextView textview;

    NodeList nodelist;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String URL = "http://json-gen.com/rest/service/get/uCSFzJgDKrjq7DKCNiQtm";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadXML().execute(URL);

        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    }


    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressbar
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressbar title
            pDialog.setTitle("Android Simple XML Parsing using DOM Tutorial");
            // Set progressbar message
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressbar
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                // Download the XML file
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                Log.e("testing ", " ==>");


                // Locate the Tag Name
//                nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("TwilioToken");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            Node nNode = nodelist.item(0);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                // Set the texts into TextViews from item nodes
                // Get the title


                Log.e("Message checking ", " ===> " + getNode("Token", eElement));
                textview.setText(getNode("Token", eElement));

            }
            // Close progressbar
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // getNode function
    private static String getNode(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
                .getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
        return nValue.getNodeValue();
    }
```

Comment: @M M I tried with this solution but getting exception like this `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT {"Data":null,"Re...@1:499 in java.io.InputStreamReader@bc741c)`

Comment: @SakibSyed I have update the answer with my full code that i have tried

Comment: @SakibSyed Also, In  onPostExecute() you can remove for loop and use  just Node nNode = nodelist.item(0); See Full Code I have Updated